# How to implement pagination with sorting in hbase

Tags: sorting, pagination, hbase

How to implement pagination with sorting in hbase ?

I have data like below

Table : datasets

---

```
rowkey       CF/Qualifier/Value
```

---

//DataSet1

```
ds1~1 : V(CF):[q1:r1q1Value,q2:r1q2Value]
ds1~2 : V(CF):[q1:r2q1Value,q2:r2q2Value]
ds1~3 : V(CF):[q1:r3q1Value,q2:r3q2Value]
ds1~4 : V(CF):[q1:r4q1Value,q2:r4q2Value]
```

//DataSet2

```
ds2~1 : V(CF):[q1:r1q1Value]
ds2~2 : V(CF):[q1:r2q1Value]
ds2~3 : V(CF):[q1:r3q1Value]
```

I am keeping 1 or more datasets data in the table datasets.
ds1 is first dataset ( has 4 records , with 2 qualifiers)
ds2 is first dataset ( has 3 records, with only 1 qualifier )

i would retrieve only ds1 or ds2 records using prefix filter.

So i need to sort them and show in UI in pages, so while retrieving i don't want to retrieve all records(eagerly) , i have to retrieve only first 100 records sorted by Qualifier 1 and then when user click next page , then i will retrieve next 100 records with same sorting field .

How to implement pagination along with sorting by particular qualifier, it would be great if you help to achieve this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [PageFilter](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/PageFilter.html).
Also please find this blog which will be helpful:
http://www.techsquids.com/bd/pagination-with-hbase/